# I can't run React aplications, I get an error

Tags: reactjs

When I try to run `npm start` I get this error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\REACT/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\REACT\package.json'npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-06T19_01_17_681Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Well why _are_ you trying to run NPM commands in a directory that doesn't contain a package file?

Answer (score 0):

it means `package.json` is omitted. You have to run `npm start` on the same level with package.json. Try to run `ls` and check whether your location is correct

Answer (score 0):

Just type in the terminal.

`cd (folder name[when you create-react-app])`

example: `cd fitness`

And then: `npm start`